# How to join a table in laravel with if condition so that data will be in same array

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have a table ps_ac_transcations where transaction details are entered as in this scenario
ac_type = credit_sales and packed_oil_other,
i need a way to join ps_op_credit_sales if ac_type == credit_sales elseif ac_type == packed_oil_other join ps_op_nonfuel_product_sales table

and i need data in the correct order as it is in the ps_ac_transcations table
i need to check this condition for further join based on if the table is ps_op_credit_sales  or ps_op_nonfuel_product_sales.

i have both queries as follows and i need an idea to make this as one query or any other method to get data as an array, i need this as one data so that i can populate in blade file and it should be in orderby ps_ac_transcations.id.

```
$credit_sales = AcTranscations::where('ps_ac_transcations.pump_id',24)
->join('ps_op_credit_sales','ps_op_credit_sales.id','ps_ac_transcations.ac_type_id')
->where('ps_ac_transcations.ac_type',"credit_sales")->get();


  $credit_sales = AcTranscations::where('ps_ac_transcations.pump_id',24)
    ->join('ps_op_nonfuel_product_sales','ps_op_nonfuel_product_sales.id','ps_ac_transcations.ac_type_id')
    ->where('ps_ac_transcations.ac_type',"packed_oil_other")->get();
```

Comment: the dynamic relationship would suit your need https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#dynamic-relationships

Comment: I found a way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution to this
first fetch the data without joining other tables which is dynamic that changes on condition like as follows

$dealer_statement = AcTranscations::where('ps_ac_transcations.pump_id',24)
->join('ps_ac_transcation_head','ps_ac_transcation_head.id','ps_ac_transcations.head_id')
->leftjoin('ps_ac_transcation_details','ps_ac_transcation_details.ac_trans_id','ps_ac_transcations.trans_id')
->where('ps_ac_transcations.head_id',$dealer_id)
->whereBetween('ps_ac_transcations.ac_date', [$from_date, $to_date])
->select('ps_ac_transcations.id','ps_ac_transcations.ac_type As particulars','ps_ac_transcation_details.description','ps_ac_transcations.debit_credit','ps_ac_transcations.ac_date','ps_ac_transcations.amount','ps_ac_transcations.ac_date','ps_ac_transcations.ac_type_id','ps_ac_transcations.ac_type')
->orderBY('ps_ac_transcations.id')
->get();

Ok, after this we can join dynamic tables based on condition like if its fuel_unloading then join ps_op_fuel_unloading and append needed data with the main query.
hope its useful

```
foreach($dealer_statement as $cost){
  if($cost->ac_type == "fuel_unloading")
  {
     $dealer_products = AcTranscations::where('ps_ac_transcations.pump_id',24)
 ->join('ps_ac_transcation_head','ps_ac_transcation_head.id','ps_ac_transcations.head_id')
 ->join('ps_op_fuel_unloading','ps_op_fuel_unloading.id','ps_ac_transcations.ac_type_id')
 ->join('ps_op_unloading_products','ps_op_unloading_products.unloading_id','ps_op_fuel_unloading.id')
 ->join('ps_fuel_products','ps_fuel_products.id','ps_op_unloading_products.product_id')
 ->join('ps_fuel_types','ps_fuel_types.id','ps_fuel_products.fuel_id')
 ->leftjoin('ps_ac_transcation_details','ps_ac_transcation_details.ac_trans_id','ps_ac_transcations.trans_id')
 ->where('ps_ac_transcations.ac_type_id',$cost->ac_type_id)
 ->select('ps_op_fuel_unloading.id','ps_fuel_types.fuel_name','ps_op_fuel_unloading.invoice_no')
 ->first();

 $cost->product = $dealer_products->fuel_name;
 $cost->invoice_no = $dealer_products->invoice_no;

  }
  else
  {
   $cost->product = "";
   $cost->invoice_no ="";
  }
```

Comment: you will meet 1+N SQL performance problem